# Converting from UTM to Lat/Long coordinates given a Proj4 String

Tags: gis, geo, utm, proj

I would like to convert an Easting/Northing coordinate to Latitude/Longitude given the following information.

- Datum: `QND95 / Qatar National Grid`
- Proj4 String: `+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +towgs84=-119.425,-303.659,-11.0006,1.1643,0.174458,1.09626,3.65706 +no_defs`
- Ellipsoid: `Hayford Intl 1924 (a=6378388, b=6356911.94612795)`

Any pointers on how to use a Proj4 library to figure this out is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The EPSG website does this transformation correctly. I would like to know how to reproduce this programmatically:

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2932&t_srs=4326&x=363377.0000000&y=169393.0000000

Comment: You should post a complete example (have a look at the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Please post the code, including tests.

Comment: I am not looking to modify my existing code. I think correctly setting up this problem using a Proj4 library can solve this issue. I am going to edit the question to remove any mention of previous code.